# VB.NET z-order (ordering forms with ownership)

Tags: vb.net

I have situation when opening several "owned" forms from my form.

```
            Dim f As New ownedform
            With f
                .Owner = Me
                .Show()
            End With
```

That works OK.
But I have a question.
Can I somehow by pressing some button on "owner" or "owned" form to get "owner" form to become a toplevel and pop over "owned" forms?

I try a simplest with ".BringToFront" but that don't work.

Answer (score 0):

BringToFront only for controls to set z-order .

but you can make that . first write this code in form1

```
    Me.Hide()
    Dim frm As New form2

    frm .ShowDialog()
```

---

thien write this code in form2

```
    Me.Hide()
    Dim frm As New form1
    frm .ShowDialog()
```

---